# java.time Comparison Is Not Consistent

Tags: java, java-time

I'm using `LocalData` objects in my code, and I've noticed that using 
`compareTo` method is not consistent.
I use the `compareTo` method in order to get the difference (in days) 
between the two dates.
However, it seems like it only works for the dates in the same months.

I'm attaching a code snippet to demonstrate this issue:

```java
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class timeComparison {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate valentinesDay = LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 14);
        LocalDate darwinDay = LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 12);
        LocalDate leapDay = LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 29);
        LocalDate superTuesday = LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 3);

        String valentinesVsDarwin = MessageFormat.format(
                "Valentine day is {0} days after Darwin day",
                valentinesDay.compareTo(darwinDay)
        );
        System.out.println(valentinesVsDarwin);

        String darwinVsLeap = MessageFormat.format(
                "Leap day is {0} days after Darwin day",
                leapDay.compareTo(darwinDay)
        );
        System.out.println(darwinVsLeap);

        String superTuesdayVsLeap = MessageFormat.format(
                "Super Tuesday is {0} days after leap day",
                superTuesday.compareTo(leapDay)
        );
        System.out.println(superTuesdayVsLeap);
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Valentine day is 2 days after Darwin day
Leap day is 17 days after Darwin day
Super Tuesday is 1 days after leap day
```

I was expecting to get `Super Tuesday is 3 days after leap day`.

I would like to know what causes the problem 
and how can I get the difference between two separate dates.

Comment: `compareTo` is _not_ meant for this use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### TL;DR

***The `compareTo` method is not meant for this use.***
It is meant to be an indicator of order, not show time differences.

#### Solving the Mystery

In order to understand this better one can look at the source code of `LocalDate`.
On any IDE you can choose "Go To => Implementation" to view the source code.

```java
public int compareTo(ChronoLocalDate other) {
    return other instanceof LocalDate ? this.compareTo0((LocalDate)other) : super.compareTo(other);
}

int compareTo0(LocalDate otherDate) {
    int cmp = this.year - otherDate.year;
    if (cmp == 0) {
        cmp = this.month - otherDate.month;
        if (cmp == 0) {
            cmp = this.day - otherDate.day;
        }
    }

    return cmp;
}
```

From the above source code, you can learn that the `compareTo` method 
***does not*** return the difference between the date in days, but rather the 
difference between dates in the first parameter that has a difference 
(it could be years, could be months, or could be days).

#### What Is the Purpose of `compareTo` Methods

In order the understand the above code and its purpose,
one would need to understand a little bit how comparison in Java works.
Java's `LocalDate` class implements `ChronoLocalDate`, 
which is a comparable object.
This means that this object is capable of comparing itself with another object.
In order to do so, the class itself must implement the `java.lang.Comparable` 
interface to compare its instances.
As described in [Java's API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that 
>   implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's natural ordering, 
>   and the class's compareTo method is referred to as its natural 
>   comparison method.

Moreover, the method detail of the `compareTo` method is the following:

> **Compares** this object with the specified object for order.
>   **Returns** a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object 
>   is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Meaning, that in order for the comparison to work we need to return an integer that corresponds with the above ruling. 
Therefore, the number itself doesn't have any meaning, 
rather than being an indication of the "order" of the objects. 
That is why the method, as shown above, does not calculate the difference in days but rather seeks the immediate indication for the natural order of the objects: first in years, then in months, and in the ends in days.
When you were comparing dates that had a different mount - the method showed just that.
The same would apply if you were to compare between a date in 
2020 and a date in 2018 - you would get 2 / -2 as a result.

#### How You Should Measure Data Difference

We found out that `compareTo` isn't meant to be used as a measurement tool of date difference.
You can use either `Period` or `ChronoUnit`, depending on your needs.
From Java's [Period and Duration tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html):

> #### ChronoUnit
>
> The `ChronoUnit` enum, discussed in the The Temporal Package, defines the 
>   units used to measure time.
>   The `ChronoUnit.between` method is useful when 
>   you want to measure an amount of time in a single unit of time only, 
>   such as days or seconds.
>   The between method works with all temporal-based 
>   objects, but it returns the amount in a single unit only.
>
> #### Period
>
> To define an amount of time with date-based values (years, months, days), 
>   use the `Period` class.
>   The `Period` class provides various get methods, 
>   such as `getMonths`, `getDays`, and `getYears`, so that you can extract the 
>   amount of time from the period.
>   The total period of time is represented by all three units together: 
>   months, days, and years.
>   To present the amount of time measured in a single 
>   unit of time, such as days, you can use the `ChronoUnit.between` method.

Here's a code snippet demonstrating the usage of the mentioned above methods:

```java
jshell> import java.time.LocalDate;

jshell> LocalDate darwinDay = LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 12);
darwinDay ==> 2020-02-12

jshell> LocalDate leapDay = LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 29);
leapDay ==> 2020-02-29

jshell> leapDay.compareTo(darwinDay);
 ==> 17

jshell> import java.time.Period;

jshell> Period.between(darwinDay, leapDay).getDays();
 ==> 17

jshell> import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

jshell> ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(darwinDay, leapDay);
 ==> 17

jshell> LocalDate now = LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 28);
now ==> 2020-03-28

jshell> LocalDate yearAgo = LocalDate.of(2019, 3, 28);
yearAgo ==> 2019-03-28

jshell> yearAgo.compareTo(now);
 ==> -1

jshell> Period.between(yearAgo, now).getDays();
 ==> 0

jshell> ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(yearAgo, now);
 ==> 366
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was expecting to get Super Tuesday is 3 days after leap day.

This was a wrong expectation. See how Java compared two instances of `LocalDate`:

```
int compareTo0(LocalDate otherDate) {
    int cmp = (year - otherDate.year);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        cmp = (month - otherDate.month);
        if (cmp == 0) {
            cmp = (day - otherDate.day);
        }
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

Since the year was same (2020), it gave you the difference between months which is `3 - 2 = 1`.

You should use `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit::between` to find the number of days between two instances of `LocalDate`.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 29), LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 3)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
34
```

Comment: Wrong answer. Never use `Period` to determine difference in days because there can also be months or years. Use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(...)` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MenoHochschild for the valuable feedback. I've updated my answer accordingly.